# Jquery $(this) not working but $('selector') works

Tags: jquery, this, selector

So i am sending an ajax request as below

```
$('a.new_thumb_update').click(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    share_id = $(this).attr('share_id');

    $.post('http://studeez.net/resource_layout_files/includes/thumbs_up.php',
    {share_id:share_id},
    function(data)
    {
        alert(data);
        $(this).parent().parent().find('div.thumbs_up').hide();
    });
});
```

The code functions well as upto  the callback function where i get the alert feedback .

```
$(this).parent().parent().find('div.thumbs_up').hide();
```

If i replace $(this) with the actual element, it works. as shown below

```
$('a.new_thumb_update').parent().parent().find('div.thumbs_up').hide();
```

Comment: The reason the `$(this)` isn't working in there is because you've entered another function. `$(this)` is now referring to the object you called `$.post` on, which is nothing

Answer (score 5):

You need to cache `$(this)` here:

```
$('a.new_thumb_update').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $self = $(this);
    share_id = $self.attr('share_id');

    $.post('http://studeez.net/resource_layout_files/includes/thumbs_up.php', {
        share_id: share_id
    }, function (data) {
        alert(data);
        $self.parent().parent().find('div.thumbs_up').hide();
    });
});
```

as `$(this)` is not accessible in the jQuery ajax `$.post` method.

Comment: ah! I can't believe this little piece of code has kept me occupied over lunch hour.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$('a.new_thumb_update').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    share_id = $(this).attr('share_id');
    var self=this;// assign this to self and use it
    $.post('http://studeez.net/resource_layout_files/includes/thumbs_up.php',
      {share_id:share_id},
      function(data){
        alert(data);
        $(self).parent().parent().find('div.thumbs_up').hide();// use self instead of this
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a.new_thumb_update').click(function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
    var _this=$(this);// set this in here
    share_id = _this.attr('share_id');

    $.post('http://studeez.net/resource_layout_files/includes/thumbs_up.php',
    {share_id:share_id},
    function(data)
    {
        alert(data);
        _this.parent().parent().find('div.thumbs_up').hide();
    });
});
```